# Arduino - use two pins to activate two circuits that use lower voltage than the Arduino's

Tags: arduino, control

I am an absolute beginner in electronics. I have the following question for which i ask you to help with an idea:

- We have a circuit in which an Arduino (Attiny85) activates one of two optocouplers (never both at the same time and the order does not matter).
- The optocouplers need to be activated by a 1.2v power supply.
- The optocouplers are used to short two wires.
- Here is the [datasheet for the optocoupler](http://datasheet.octopart.com/TLP421(BL)-Toshiba-datasheet-134592.pdf) (but basically anything similar will do)
- The circuit has a 5V power supply.
- I don't want to pass too much current through the Arduino. My solutions include transistors but i'm open to other ideas.

The question:

- **What is the most efficient way of activating the optocouplers ?**

My solutions so far:

- Use the 5v supply to power the Arduino. On the Arduino output pins use two MOSFETs (as switches) and two voltage dividers. This results in power loss through heat.
- Use the 5v supply to power the Arduino. On the Arduino output pins use two MOSFETs (as switches) and two buck converters. This works but i would like to make it more efficient and use only one buck converter. Would it be possible to do so ?

Here is a MS Paint schematic of the best circuit that I've thought so far: 
[image]

I've thought about other ways but haven't found any. Do you have a better idea of what I could do ?

Please tell me if i haven't been clear and i will edit the post. Thank you !

Comment: By 1.2V I am assuming you mean a max voltage of 1.2V to turn on the LED. What current is required? Figure out the right resistor that drops 3.8V at that current and attach to the 5V.

Comment: Hi. Yes, that is my first solution but i'm looking for something more efficient, if it exists.

Comment: You could PWM the 5V to generate a supply for the leds with a suitable holding cap and feedback to the micro...

Comment: Or maybe use something like a MAX829 https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/725

Comment: Please post the link to your optocoupler datasheet.

Comment: Hi. I've updated the post with the datasheet of the optocoupler and a schematic

Comment: Trevor - thank you for the ideas but i don't know how i could integrate the MAX829. Regarding the second message, i didn't understand what you said after "generate a supply for the leds"

Comment: How much current do you want to drive the Opto with?  You don't need much to turn it on, depending on how much current will be passing through the output side.  Normally optos are just driven with maybe 5-10mA with a series resistor, calculated as Trevor mentioned.  Why do you feel you need so much added complexity to reduce that current, or do you feel you need higher current?

Comment: AngeloQ - from lack of knowledge and experience, i just overthought the whole thing. Using a resistor in series is exactly what i'll do. Tom Carpenter explained it prefectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are trying to drive an opto-coupler from the ATTiny and nothing else.

If this is the case then the \$1.2\mathrm{V}\$ that you quote for the opto-coupler is the forward voltage at \$10\mathrm{mA}\$ as per the datasheet:

[image: Opto-Coupler LED Characteristics]

Opto-coupler inputs are nothing more than an LED. In any LED circuit all you need is a resistor to drop the voltage to the required level as the current draw is fairly constant.

The ATTiny I/O pins will happily sink \$10\mathrm{mA}\$ of current, so you don't even need a transistor or other external switch.

Simply put a \$390\Omega\$ series resistor for each of the LEDs and your job is done.

$$R_{LED} \geq \frac{V_{cc} - V_f}{I_f} = \frac{5-1.2}{0.01} = 380\Omega$$

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Thank you for taking the time to write this answer.